# Is taraweeh for women considered as sunnat or nafil?

Tags: salat, women, taraweeh

The taraweeh salah for women is sunnat or nafil?
Just want to clear it more that when a girl is performing the taraweeh salah then we wilk the girl will perform it as sunnat salah or nafil salah

Comment: All taraweeh is nafl for both men and women.

Comment: Are u sure sayyid because it is very important for me and someone told me that perform it as sunnat so please if you are sure then tell me and if you have any doubt then please ask from anyone else to confirm it

Answer (score 5):

**Is there a difference between sunna and nafl?**

For me it is the same, maybe only under some circumstances in (technical term) fiqh language اصطلاح الفقهاء it makes a slight difference of the level of tawab (rewards). 
But for example all nafl is sunnah!

And in general Nafl=Sunnah (they are synonyms) as it is a kind of "extra or optional worship" the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) made which is not prescribed by Allah in the Qur'an...

This meaning can be concluded from the following Hadith:

> On the authority of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) who
>   said: The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon
>   him) said, “Verily Allah ta’ala has said: ‘Whosoever shows enmity to a
>   wali (friend) of Mine, then I have declared war against him. And My
>   servant does not draw near to Me with anything more loved to Me than
>   the religious duties I have obligated upon him. And My servant
>   continues to draw near to me with nafil (supererogatory) deeds until I
>   Love him. When I Love him, I am his hearing with which he hears, and
>   his sight with which he sees, and his hand with which he strikes, and
>   his foot with which he walks. Were he to ask [something] of Me, I
>   would surely give it to him; and were he to seek refuge with Me, I
>   would surely grant him refuge.’ ” [Al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/91)

**Now to your questions:**

When it comes to worshiping acts then any basic kind of worship (prayer, fast, hajj, zakat etc.) which is prescribed or lawful for a man has the same level of prescription for a woman. With one note for optional worships: If the husband doesn't allow his wife to perform a optional worship, for some reasonable matter she should follow his orders!

So taraweeh prayer as a nafl or sunnah prayer has at least the same level of tawab or prescription for women, even if scholars (especially those who say that a woman should pray at home) say it's preferable for a woman to pray at home.

**For the technical term:** The Hanafi, Shafi'i and Hanbali school have defined it as sunnah muakkadah, while Maliki school call it mandubah. (Source [fiqh according the 4 madhabs](http://islamport.com/d/2/fqh/1/29/315.html) in Arabic)

Here are some fatwas: 
[Do woman need to pray tarawih?](https://islamqa.info/en/3457) and [how woman should pray tarawih at home?](https://islamqa.info/en/222751)

Comment: But there's also differences in lawfulness relating to menses, hijab, jihad, and whether jumuah prayer is obligatory.

Comment: @MediSaif... can u please provide evidence what you said "With one note for optional worships: **If the husband doesn't allow his wife to perform optional worship, for some reasonable matter she should follow his orders!**" If one's wife wants to pray optional prayer, the husband should allow her to pray...I srsly don't understand what you mean by "follow his orders". I say a husband requests not order (mind the connotation that 2 means very different) her wife to feed her newborn instead of praying....then yes, it's the wife's fault becuz he didn't care not becuz he didn't follow orders.

Comment: Beneficial post. JazakAllahu khayr @Medi1saif

Answer (score 0):

its sunnat and niyat will be of sunnat namaz