# can nafl prayers make up for obligatory ones?

Tags: salat

I have been hearing people say that there is a haadith which states that nafl prayers can makeup for obligatory ones if they are invalid. Is this true?

Comment: Well maybe my Answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25516/womens-taraweeh-is-sunnat-or-nafil/25545#25545 or a look at this discussion http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=199588 could be helpful

Comment: I dont think your question is clear. What do you mean by "if they are invalid" and what actually do you mean by "makeup for"? Do you mean they are equal in value to fard prayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked deep into Bukhari and Muslim but could not find something like this. One thing I found was about the value of nafl in ramdan. There is a Hadith about which Islamic scholars thought to be daeef which states:

> The Prophet peace be upon him said: “Whoever draws near to Allaah during it (Ramadaan) with a single characteristic from the characteristics of (voluntary) goodness, he is like whoever performs an obligatory act in other times. And whoever performs an obligatory act during it, he is like whoever performed seventy obligatory acts in other times.” – Sahih Ibn Khuzaymah, no. 1887.

It is derived from this Hadith that a nafl equals to sunnat or fard in ramdan. But i said this is termed as daeef and there is no other Hadith like this. Do you Have reference to any book?

Comment: No. I only heard it from other people and I also read it in a book that I don't remember the name of.